# Jquery Mobile check box value invalid in MVC3 view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, checkbox, viewmodel

I'm learning Jquery Mobile.  I'm trying to set up the logon page for my .NET MVC3 site.  My controller is just the standard MVC3 account controller.

Here is my Jquery Mobile page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mobile Logon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
           $.extend(  $.mobile , {
            ajaxEnabled: false
          });
        });
    </script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="header">

        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" data-icon="arrow-l" rel="external" >Back</a>
        <h1>Logon</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role = "content">        
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful.")

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", FormMethod.Post, null))
        {
            <label for="Username">User Name (e-mail address)</label><input type="email" name="Username" />
            <label for="Password">Password</label><input type="password" name="Password" />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" data-theme="c" />Remember Me</label>
            <button type="submit" value="Log On"></button>
        }
        <center>or</center>

        @using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Get, null ))
        {
            <button type="submit" value="Register for an account" data-transition="flip"></button>  
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

When I test the page, if I leave the "Remember Me" box unchecked, then everything works fine.  However, **if I check the box and click "Log On", then the controller says that the model is invalid.**  As I step through the code, I notice that it also thinks that the value for "RememberMe" is false whether the box is checked or not.

Here is the view model for the logon page

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail address")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what your reasoning is for not using the built-in HtmlHelpers?

Comment: First, I was getting sample code from the Jquery Mobile site.  Second, I was hoping to use type=email and type=password to take advantage of the smart keyboards on mobile devices.  As far as the checkbox goes, I was just following the same pattern.  Is there a reason why it wouldn't work like this?

Comment: There's no reason why you can't take advantage of those things whilst using the HtmlHelpers. I'll post an answer as an example. This could potentially be why it's not working, as the HtmlHelper provides both ID and Name attributes, but also a Value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your extra mobile attributes when using the `HtmlHelpers`, an example is below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { type = "email" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RememberMe, new { data_theme = "c" })
```

MVC 3 converts underscores in attribute names to dashes, so your data-theme attribute remains in-tact. I have just tested this and it works perfectly for your needs.

Comment: I get an error "no overload for method 'TextBoxFor' takes 3 arguments".

Comment: Edit: Apologies.. I included the default value, of which there isn't an overload for TextBoxFor. I have edited my answer.

Comment: As far as the model goes, the problem is fixed, but I'm left with a checkbox that is like 1 pixel by 1 pixel.  I noticed this happened before if I didn't wrap the checkbox with a label.

Comment: That's a stylesheet issue. I would fire up your markup debug tool (FireBug, Chrome developer tools, etc) and find the cause of that. If it needs to be wrapped in a label, you can wrap it in a label without an issue.

Comment: Alright, as soon as I wrap it in a label, it works fine.  I guess I can look into the css issue later if I need to.  Thanks for the help.